# Return alert/message in asp.net MVC from controller without Ajax?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my application if someone does not log in successfully I want to take and return something like a JavaScript alert to notify them. The problem is I can not use a Ajax call to return this JavaScript alert. Is there any other way to return some sort or alert or message?

Comment: Why you need an alert ? Are you not using the normal form submit and validation helper methods to show the error message ?

Comment: I am not using a form, because the way I have the page setup multiple different buttons on this page all use the same ID text box to function so a form would not work.

Comment: If you do not have a form, how is this happening "someone does not login successfully" ????

Comment: @RainMan Could you show the login View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the message to be shown in the TempData (inside your controller in the error case). Then return a view to be shown.

```
public const string FlashMessageTempDataKey = "_flash";
controller.TempData[FlashMessageTempDataKey] = "The Message (Grandmaster Flash and the Furious Five)";
```

And then check whether the TempData is present in your view.

```
public static MvcHtmlString Flash(this HtmlHelper helper) {
    var message = helper.ViewContext.Controller.TempData[FlashMessageTempDataKey] as string;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (message != null) {
        sb.AppendLine("<script>");
        sb.AppendLine("$(function() {");
        sb.AppendFormat("flash('{0}');", HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(message));
        sb.AppendLine("});</script>");
     }
     return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
}
```

Use this extension method as `@Html.Flash()`, e.g. in your _layout.cshtml. It assumes that there is some global JS function `flash(message)` and jQuery available on the page to display the message.

```
function flash(message) {
    alert(message);
}
```

Note that with this mechanism, the message will be shown on the next page the user loads, which must not necessarely be the page that triggered the error (e.g. if he has multiple browser tabs open).

Comment: Glad I could help you out :)